# Ubuntu 16.04 server amd64 install failed

Tags: web-services, docker, ubuntu-16.04, x86-64, i386

I created a bootable usb using etcher on Mac os. The PC I installed on is a Dell Inspiron with Windows 7 64bit. Installation fails at the select and install step. None of the packages are able to install, causing the install to abort. I was only able to install Ubuntu 16.04 i386. Which is not capable of running Docker ce.

Comment: This belongs on askubuntu.com.  It's not a programming question.

Comment: DId you try converting Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS iso found here(https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) to the usb installer using etcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) on your current Windows 7 64-bits host, which allows you to define a VM with any Ubuntu you want (I would select the latest 17.10)

That way, all you need is an iso file (no need for a bootable USB device)

And you will be able to run docker in that VM.

Comment: Great idea, except hardrive is wiped. So Ubuntu is my only available option

Comment: @OmarVivar Would a Ubuntu 17.10 works better? Is your BIOS an UEFI one? Does it has a secure boot option? How was formatted your bootable USB key? GPT or old legacy MBR?